# Return custom JSON response from ListAPIView Django 3.0 Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have created an API using DRF That is able to list and view particular records based on the URL pattern specified. For example:

for the request:

```
curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_details/120001/
```

I am able to get a response:

```
[
    {
        "subject": "Data Structures",
        "course": "CSE"
    },
    {
        "subject": "Thermodynamics",
        "course": "Chemistry"
    },
    {
        "subject": "Organic Chemistry",
        "course": "Chemistry"
    },
    {
        "subject": "Optics",
        "course": "Physics"
    }
]
```

Where '120001' is the user_id the database is searched against.
But the I want the response in the following format:

```
{'Chemistry': ['Thermodynamics', 'Organic Chemistry'], 'CSE': ['Data Structures'], 'Physics': ['Optics']}
```

(content wise, I am not considering indentation and other factors)

While I am able to write code for the logic of how to create and populate this dictionary, **I am unable to figure out how to return this as response and from where.**

I am using **generics.ListAPIView** as the view class.

**Here is my model (models.py):**

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(null = False, max_length=10)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    course = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject
```

**Serializer (serializers.py):**

```
class SubjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Subject
        fields = ['subject', 'course']
```

and, **views.py (for the first output in default format):**

```
class SubjectView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = SubjectSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        username = self.kwargs['user_id']
        return Subject.objects.filter(user_id = username).only('subject','course')
```

I have written a logic to create the dictionary to send as response (as described in my desired output) by extracting values using **Subject.objects.values(....)** and then looping through the results to create my dictionary but I just don't get where (that is, which function) to write it in and return from.

**Is there any function provided by the generics.ListAPIView class that can allow me to do this? And if not, then what other alternative approach can I try?**

I am an absolute beginner at Django and any help will be appreciated. Also, it will be of great help if anyone can suggest me a practical guide/tutorial/playlist from where I can learn DRF through code examples to speed up my learning process.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You need to override `to_representation` method of `Serializer`

from [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context)

> There are some cases where you need to provide extra context to the
>   serializer in addition to the object being serialized.

```
class SubjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Subject
        fields = ['subject', 'course']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super(SubjectSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        # manipulate data here 
        return data
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I could solve the problem by writing my own implementation of `APIView` class but I looked into the documentation and several examples of `to_representation()` and it will surely come handy in future :)